# Read data from XML file into SWF file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have an xml file with this structure :

```
<onlineTrain>
  <sensor>
    <sendorId>612</sendorId>
    <speed>28.923314981882</speed>
    <trainId>2</trainId>
    <xlocation>100</xlocation>
    <ylocation>307</ylocation>

  </sensor>
  <sensor>
    <sendorId>61122</sendorId>
    <speed>218.923314981882</speed>
    <trainId>2</trainId>
    <xlocation>1200</xlocation>
    <ylocation>3207</ylocation>

  </sensor>
</onlineTrain>
```

I need to read all values `sensor` in flash swf file so i use this part of code to do this :

```
xmlList = xml.children();
trace(xml.people[0].Person[0].sensorId);
```

but it doesn't work .any ideas will be appreciated .I need to access all values .How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a non-existent nodes. The correct code should look like this:

```
trace(xml.sensor[0].sendorId); // 612
trace(xml.sensor[1].sendorId); // 61122
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to treat each value of sendorId (not sensorId !). Since XMLList is iterable, the easiest way would be :

```
var xml:XML =
    <onlineTrain>
      <sensor>
        <sendorId>612</sendorId>
        <speed>28.923314981882</speed>
        <trainId>2</trainId>
        <xlocation>100</xlocation>
        <ylocation>307</ylocation>
      </sensor>
      <sensor>
        <sendorId>61122</sendorId>
        <speed>218.923314981882</speed>
        <trainId>2</trainId>
        <xlocation>1200</xlocation>
        <ylocation>3207</ylocation>
      </sensor>
    </onlineTrain>;

for each(var element:XML in xml.sensor.sendorId)
    trace(element.toString());
```

If you want to create a Vector/Array from this list, just cast the Values to the desired type and push them in  an empty Vector/Array

The notation xml.sensor.sendorId mays seem strange at first sight because you call a property (sendorId) on a list (xml.sendor), but that's the kind of strange but powefurl things you can do with E4X.

More info at [official documentation for E4X](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html)